# Any word for beautiful but unknown places?

Tags: word-choice

I wonder that if there is a word for telling that a place where is beautiful or touristic but not everybody know about it, like unknown version of eiffel tower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say somethings like:

1. [**off the beaten track**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/off-the-beaten-track)

   > ### off the beaten track
   >
   > (US also **off the beaten path**)
   >
   > ##### in a place where few people go, far from any main roads and towns:
   >
   > - The farmhouse we stayed in was completely off the beaten track.

   This is a idiom for representing what you were trying to make an example of.
2. [**hidden gem**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hidden-gem)

   > Hidden gems mean that something is really amazing and beautiful, but not many people now about.

   The main thing is that this isn't specific to "places", but it's the most similar to what you were trying to make an example of. You could say:

   > The "unknown version of the Eiffel Tower" is a hidden gem in France.

Both of these are the viable options I prefer.